# Why isn't the unsigned long long int showing the right value in C?

Tags: c

I am writing a program that converts decimal to unbalanced ternary but when I take a decimal input of of 1000000000, it will show a undesired value. I have used `unsigned long long int` as the data type of sum which is the data that I am printing. I have calculated the ternary number of 1000000000 is 19 digits long which shouldn't be aproblem as the range of ull is 20 digits long.
I am using codeblocks in windows 10.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int N,cycle = 1,ara[100];
    while(cycle <= 100)
    {
        scanf("%d",&N);
        if(N >= 0)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while(N != 0)
            {
                ara[i] = N % 3;
                N = N / 3;
                i++;
            }
            unsigned long long int sum = 0;
            int j;
            for(j = 0;j < i;j++)
            {
                sum = sum + (ara[j]*(int)(pow(10,j)+0.5));
            }
            printf("%llu\n",sum);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        cycle++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your desired output and what is the output you currently get?

Comment: it might be because windows considers unsigned long long as a 64 bits data type

Comment: Unbalanced ternary is just a representation of a number, so it might be better to use a string to store it rather than a number whose decimal representation looks like the ternary representation of another number.

Comment: The garbage value comes from the cast to `(int)`, where you lose precision.

Comment: yes. `(int)` was creating the problem. changing it to `(unsigned long long int)` solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

When you calculate your ternary representation:

```
sum = sum + (ara[j] * (int) (pow(10, j) + 0.5));
```

the cast to `(int)` will not produce a power of ten when you exceed 10 digits for a 32-bit `int`. Cast to your target type `(unsigned long long)` here.

I can imagine that using the floating-point function `pow` can cause problems, too, because not all values of an `unsigned long long` can be represented by a `double`. Alternatively, you can calculate a "running power", where you multiply your decimal base by ten in each pass through the loop:

```
    unsigned long long int sum = 0;
    unsigned long long dec = 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        sum = sum + ara[j] * dec;
        dec *= 10;
    }
```

Comment: hey changing casting from `int` to `unsigned long long int` worked. thx man